# Updating beginning and ending values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table structure]

I want to update the values of beginning and ending if the user enter an existing product. Is there something wrong in my update query? Thanks!

```
if(isset($_POST['status2'])){

          $rowValues = explode("//", $_POST['status2']);

          $orderId = $rowValues[0];

          $dateReceivedNo = $rowValues[1];

          $receivedDate = $_POST[$dateReceivedNo];



          mysqli_query(connect(), "UPDATE `order` SET `status` = 'RECEIVED' WHERE `order_id` = '$orderId'");

          $product = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `order_id` = '$orderId' AND branch_name = '$name' ");
          $product2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product);

          $cate = $product2['cat_name'];
          $item = $product2['item_name'];
          $prodName = $product2['product_name'];
          $quantity = $product2['quantity'];

          mysqli_query(connect(), "INSERT INTO `logs`(`log_id`, `branch_name`, `activity`, `date`) VALUES ('', '$name', 'RECEIVED ITEM ".$prodName. " ". $quantity ."', now())");

          $count = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT count(invbranch_id) AS 'countItems' FROM `inventorybranch` WHERE `cat_name` = '$cate' AND `item_name` = '$item' AND `product_name` = '$prodName'");
          $count2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count);

          if($count2['countItems'] > 0){
            mysqli_query(connect(), "UPDATE `inventorybranch` SET `beginning` = (`beginning` + '$quantity'), `date` = NOW() WHERE `cat_name` = '$cate' AND `item_name` = '$item' AND `product_name` = '$prodName' AND `status` = 'DELIVERED'");

             mysqli_query(connect(), "UPDATE `inventorybranch` SET `quantity` = (`quantity` + '$quantity'), `date` = NOW() WHERE `cat_name` = '$cate' AND `item_name` = '$item' AND `product_name` = '$prodName' AND `status` = 'DELIVERED'");
          }

          else{
            mysqli_query(connect(), "INSERT INTO `inventorybranch` VALUES ('','','$cate','','$item','','$prodName','$name','$quantity','$quantity','','','', now())");
          }

          mysqli_query(connect(), "UPDATE `inventoryho` SET quantity = (quantity-'$quantity') WHERE cat_name = '$cate' AND item_name = '$item' AND product_name = '$prodName'"); 
          mysqli_query(connect(), "UPDATE `order` SET `date_receive` = now() WHERE `order_id` = '$orderId'");


}
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Most likely because you are looking for `status = 'delivered'` and I don't see `status` on your structure

Comment: Thanks! Got confused haha